# How to read DimeSize from .mhd images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a dataset containing ultrasound images. For each image I have one .raw and one .mhd format images. I am using matlab. When I go to the directory of the images in matlab directory, when I click on the .mhd file I get the information below:

```
ObjectType = Image
NDims = 3
BinaryData = True
BinaryDataByteOrderMSB = False
CompressedData = False
TransformMatrix = 1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
CenterOfRotation = 0  0  0
AnatomicalOrientation = RAI
Offset = 0  0  0
ElementSpacing = 0.308       0.154        1.54
DimSize = 669  1102     1
ElementNumberOfChannels = 1
ElementType = MET_UCHAR
ElementDataFile = patient0001_2CH_ED.raw
```

how can I get the DimSize without clicking on the image? I mean what is the code for getting the image dimension?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of file format are your .mhd files? Are they "Insight Meta-Image" files? If so, there's a MathWorks File Exchange project that claims to be able to read them: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29344-read-medical-data-3d.